# help showing apps with error "lacks Mime Type key"

Tags: apt

I am 82 years young but not gend up too much on linux. When i could not show my apps installed or software app I tried"update-desktop-database -v"  in terminal and had error "/usr/local/share/applications ?? no such file or directory  and then a list of files all with" lacks Mime Type key " can anyone please help.

Comment: What is your goal? If you just want the start menu, you don't need to run any commands. Just click the top left and see https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-apps-open.html.en

Comment: Not all files will pass a `mime` check. The message itself is just a warning. See: https://github.com/clearlinux/distribution/issues/670